# Copying arrays starting at particular point in destination

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am quite new to C programming, but was wondering if there is a function that allows you to copy a char array into another char array starting at a particular index, other than using a for loop?

For example, I want to copy the entire contents of `source` into `buffer` using, say, element 4 of `buffer` as the starting point.  `source` will be binary data.  Can `memcpy` do this?

Comment: Read about the `memcpy` function.

Comment: something like this -> char source[100], buffer[100];
....
memcpy( source+4, buffer, 10 );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `memcpy` is designed to copy data. The source and destination can be arbitrary locations in memory (as long as it is memory you are allowed to read/write).

In answer to your specific question:

```
memcpy(buffer+4, source, length);
```

If the source and target areas may overlap, use `memmove` instead.

```
memmove(buffer+4, source, length);
```

Comment: It really does look so simple looking at that, that I'm quite embarrassed that I asked the question.  Anyway, thanks for this, does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, memcpy can do that. Just try

```
memcpy(buffer + 4, source, numberOfBytesToCopy);
```

This is nothing memcpy specific. It's just simple pointer arithemtic.

Comment: I would add that `numberOfElementsToCopy` is only valid if the size of each element is 1 (as `char`, in the question is)... but for a more general solution, you would want to multiply that by `sizeof(elementType)` to get the proper memory length.

Comment: You're right. I just confused it. Patch applied ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` of course:

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```